# Upload TAR contained file to REST PUT API using PHP CURL without extracting

Tags: rest, put, php-curl

Basically, I am facing the following issue:

I have a TAR container (no compression) of a large size (4GB). This TAR encloses several files:

- file 1
- file 2
- file 3 - the one THAT I NEED (also very large 3 GB)
- other files (it doesn't matter how many.).

I should mention that I do know where the file 3 starts (start index) and how large it is(file length) because the TAR format is relatively easy to parse.

What I need to do is **upload file 3** by using PHP Curl to a REST API.THE API endpoint is HTTP PUT and the headers are correctly set (it works if I'm uploading the entire TAR file).

So,  INFILE = TAR Container.
File 3 starts at the Xth Byte and has a length of Y bytes. I already know the X and Y value.
I need the curl to start sending data from X to Y.

What I did until now was:

```
 $fileHandle = fopen($filePath, "rb"); //File path is the one of the TAR archive
 fseek($fileHandle, $fileStartIndex, SEEK_CUR);
```

And the settings of the curl are.

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);  
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fileHandle);
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);
```

I must mention that extracting file 3 to disk is not an option at this moment as the disk space is the main purpose of the task.

My first idea was to look at the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, but the callback of this option should return a string (in my case very large one :3 GB, and it breaks the PHP variable size limit).

Has anyone succeeded in handling this kind of upload? Any other tips and trick about CURLOPT_READFUNCTION are also best appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue right now with the `curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fileHandle);` approach?

Comment: Let's say that my Curl needs to send only the bytes from index X to index Y from the file, where X is different than 0 and Y is different to the end of the file.  Somehow, I do not know how to control this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PHP curl [doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_READFUNCTION
>   A callback accepting three parameters. The
>   first is the cURL resource, the second is a stream resource provided
>   to cURL through the option CURLOPT_INFILE, and the third is the
>   maximum amount of data to be read. The callback must return a string
>   with a length equal or smaller than the amount of data requested,
>   typically by reading it from the passed stream resource. It should
>   return an empty string to signal EOF.

So a combination of `CURLOPT_INFILE` to give curl the file handle, `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` to tell curl how big the final file will be and `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` to allow curl to read from the file looks like it should do what you need.

Although curl will call your `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` with a `$length` parameter, you're free to return what you want, within the rules:

> The callback must return a string with a length equal or smaller than
>   the amount of data requested

so if you return less than `$length`, curl will keep calling your `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` until it returns `EOF` (an empty string). So you need to keep track of where you are in your file when reading in `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` and start from the last read position on each call.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that the callback function is called until it is return a string of that lenght or EOF. Nice.